# WTMP (RHEL 5/6) log maintenance - need to keep a rolling log rather than rotate

Tags: truncate, rollover, logrotate

We have a policy requirement to use items using wtmp, such as the 'last' command or GDM-Last-Login details.  We've discovered that these items will have gaps depending on when wtmp was last rotated, and need to try to work around this.

Because these gaps have been determined to be unacceptable, and keeping wtmp data in a single active logfile forever without splitting off the old data into archives is not really viable, **I'm looking for a way to rollover / age-out old wtmp entries while still keeping more recent ones**.

From some initial research I've seen this problem addressed in the Unix (AIX, SunOS) world with the use of 'fwtmp' and some pre/post logrotate scripts.  Has this been addressed in the Linux world and I've just missed it?

So far as I can tell 'fwtmp' is a Unix built-in that's not made it into RHEL 5 & 6, per searching the RHEL customer portal and some 'yum whatprovides' searches on my test boxes.

Many thanks in advance!